# Refreshing dynamic drop down options

Tags: php, jquery

I got 3 drop down boxes dependent on each other when selected. For e.g. if I select a type from  drop down 1, then drop down 2 populates only the options relevant to what i select from the first drop down box. The 3rd drop down is dependable on the 2nd drop down option.

The problem i am facing is that the options on the drop down boxes are not refreshing when i want to choose something different.

Can anyone help me?

This is my form:

```
<label>Tour Type </label>
<select id="tourtype" name="tourtype" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
    <?php
        $sql=mysql_query("Select tour_type_id,tour_name from tour_type");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $tour_type_id=$row['tour_type_id'];
            $name=$row['tour_name'];
            echo "<option value='$tour_type_id'>$name</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
<label>Country</label>
<select id="country" name="country" class="country" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
</select>
<label>Destination</label>
<select id="destination" name="destination" class="destination" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
</select>
```

This is the js at the bottom of the form:

```
<script>
    $('#tourtype').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    get_countries: 1
                },
                success: function (html) {

                    $("#country").empty();
                    $("#country").append(html);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ajax failed");
                }

            });
    });

    $('#country').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    get_destination: 1
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#destination").empty();
                    $("#destination").append(html);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ajax failed");
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Finally this is the ajax.php

```
<?php
include('../config.php');

if ($_REQUEST['get_countries']) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `tour_type_id`=" . $_REQUEST['id']);

    $countries = "";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $cid = $row['countries_id'];

        $name = $row['countries_name'];

        $countries .= "<option value='" . $cid . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }
    echo $countries;
} elseif ($_REQUEST['get_destination']) {
    $destination = "";
    $sql         = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `destination`  where `country_id` =" . $_REQUEST['id']);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $destination_id = $row['destination_id'];
        $name           = $row['destination_name'];

        $destination .= "<option value='" . $destination_id . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }
    echo $destination;
}
?>
```

Comment: Use Chrome Network & Console tabs to see if you are getting the correct output from ajax.php or if there are any js errors.

Comment: Consider formatting your answer.

Comment: What is the response you are getting from ajax.php?

Comment: i am getting the right outputs from ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. Just had to add more data to the 3 separate tables where my query is fetching the data from